# upload photo and text from form input and sending to telegram bot with php

Tags: php, telegram-bot, photo, send

html code:

```
<form action="process.php">
     <input type="text" name="name">
 <input type="file" name="photo">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

process.php:

```
define ('url',"https://api.telegram.org/bot****/");

$name = $_GET['name'];
$img=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
$chat_id = '****';
$message = urlencode("Name:".$name);
file_get_contents(url."sendmessage?text=".$message."&chat_id=".$chat_id."&parse_mode=HTML");
```

I recieve text message but photo not. I don't know how to send photo with "sendPoto" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must store the file uploaded.

in your `html` code you have error. you must add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to support `file input`.

So your `html` code must be like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="file" name="photo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In your `php` file you must first save file uploaded.

```
define ('url',"https://api.telegram.org/bot****/");

$info = pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
$newname = "newname.".$ext;

$target = 'images/'.$newname; // the path you want to upload your file
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target);
```

After that you can send this file to telegram api.

```
$chat_id = '123456'; // telegram user id
$url = url."sendPhoto?chat_id=$chat_id";

$params = [
    'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
    'photo'=>'Your site address/'.$target,
    'caption'=>$_POST['name'],
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $server_output;
```

Comment: 'caption'=>$_POST['name'], and 'chat_id'=>$user_id, why need cos "Undefined variable" and also this problem: Notice: Undefined variable: HTTPHEADER in C:\xampp\htdocs\tg\process.php on line 25

Warning: curl_setopt(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\tg\process.php on line 25
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}

Comment: yes, i edited but: {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}

Comment: is it possible to do it in localhost

Comment: 'photo'=>'images/'.$target " ?

Comment: {"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"} I checked twice but this error again. And also chacked in alive website.

Comment: source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MiYAxo0fzXN25Uh_oLVl2XRzWV1qvu3n/view?usp=sharing please, check my code

Comment: @AdhamMuzaffarov see comment on this. i would remove my comment.

Comment: @AdhamMuzaffarov yes and i comment in it. and changed it

Comment: @AdhamMuzaffarov https://docs.google.com/document/d/143y2IstlhRfmbDP8IqLfnoTZxzciI7d5SGJG8CJs9Fk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You should save the image in your Server and then pass a direct downlaod link to telegram. like this:

```
//TODO save uploded photo on myfiles/avatar1.png

// send to telegram
file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot****/sendPhoto?chat_id=1245763214&photo=http://example.com/myfiles/avatar1.png");
```

Note: When sending by URL the target file must have the correct MIME type (e.g., audio/mpeg for sendAudio, etc.).

Read sendPhoto document [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)

Comment: This doesnt work now, I dont know why. Maybe telegram API change something